# Difference between formset and formset.forms in django template tags

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, templatetags

I'm trying to loop through forms in a formset on my template. And I have seen two different ways of doing this and it doesn't seem to make a difference to my code which one I use.

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
```

And...

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset.forms %}
        {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
```

Does this make any difference? Why put .forms on the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the source of the [BaseFormset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/forms/formsets/#BaseFormSet) class:

```
def __iter__(self):
    """Yields the forms in the order they should be rendered"""
    return iter(self.forms)

@cached_property
def forms(self):
    """
    Instantiate forms at first property access.
    """
    # DoS protection is included in total_form_count()
    forms = [self._construct_form(i, **self.get_form_kwargs(i))
             for i in range(self.total_form_count())]
    return forms
```

Both methods (`for form in formset` and `for form in formset.forms`) are identical.

You see, the `__iter__` which is used for the `for` loop yields each time the `self.forms`. On the other hand, the `for form in formset.forms` iterates over the same thing, the `self.forms`.